# How $\sum_{r=m}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^r}{r!}=\int_{0}^{\lambda}\frac{e^{-u}u^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}du$

Tags: probability, statistics, integration, definite-integrals, summation

$$P(X\geq m)=\sum_{r=m}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^r}{r!};m=0,1,...$$

Show that for any $m=1,2,...$

$$P(X\geq m)=\int_{0}^{\lambda}\frac{e^{-u}u^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}du$$

I couldn't derive it also don't understand why $m$ starts from $1$? why not from $0$ ?

Comment: It doesn't start from $0$ because your second expression for $P(X\ge m)$ is terribly ill-defined for $m = 0$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams thank you , i got the answer of values of $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start by differentiating with respect to $\lambda$ which gives us the following expression:
$$
f(\lambda)=\sum_{r=m}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^r}{r!}\implies f'(\lambda)=\sum_{r=m}^{\infty}\frac{-e^{-\lambda}\lambda^r}{r!}+\sum_{r=m}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}
$$
But we have the following:
$$
\sum_{r=m}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}+\sum_{r=m}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{r}}{r!}=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}+f(\lambda)
$$
Hence:
$$
f'(\lambda)=-f(\lambda)+\sum_{r=m}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}=-f(\lambda)+\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}+f(\lambda)\\
\implies f'(\lambda)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\\
f(\lambda)=\int_0^\lambda \frac{e^{-u}u^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}du
$$

Comment: I have not understood this equation :$\sum_{r=m}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}+\sum_{r=m}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{r}}{r!}$. Could you please explain ?

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{r=m}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}=\frac{e^{-\lambda}‌​\lambda^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}+\frac{e^{-\lambda}‌​\lambda^{m}}{m!}+\frac{e^{-\lambda}‌​\lambda^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}+...=\frac{e^{-\lambda}‌​\lambda^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}+\sum_{r=m}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{r}}{r!}$